# Find $f(x_0)$ if $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \gt x_0$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, alternative-proof

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Suppose $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and  $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \gt x_0$. Prove that $f(x_0) = 0$.

**My try:** Let $a_n = x_0 + \frac{1}{n}$. So we have $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = x_0 $ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n)= 0$. By continuity we have $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} f(a_n) = f(\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n) = f(x_0)$. The result is $f(x_0) = 0$.

Is this solution correct? What are the different ways to prove that? Also I wonder if it's possible to prove $f(x_1) = 0$ for $x_1 \lt x_0$  by the same argument.

Comment: This is correct, but you can deal without sequencing : by continuity, $$f(x_0)= \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0 \\ x > x_0} f(x) = 0$$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks. Intuitively it seems correct but is it rigorous?

Comment: @S.H.W Yes. They are using the right-hand limit, which is equal to the actual limit for continuous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct. However your claim about $x_1$ is not. Consider:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x_0-x &\text { for } x < x_0 \\ 0&\text{ for } x\ge x_0\end{cases}$$

$f$ is continuous but $\ne 0$ for any $x < x_0$.

Comment: Thanks for counterexample. Would you explain why the argument fails in that case, please?

Comment: Let $a_n = x_1 + \frac 1 n$. There is some $N$ such that $a_N < x_0$. We don't know anything about $f(a_n)$ for $n \ge N$ (so in my counterexample I chose what I want).

Comment: I see. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

A topological way to see the result is to say that
$$A = f^{-1}(\lbrace 0 \rbrace)$$

is closed (as the continuous preimage of $\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ which is closed), and contains $(x, +\infty)$, therefore it contains $x$.

Comment: Very clever! Thanks.

Comment: We know that $A$ is closed and contains $(x, +\infty )$. Why this implies that $A$ contains $x$? I mean how we know it's the only way for fulfilling the closeness condition.

Comment: Because as a closed set containing $(x, +\infty)$, $A$ has to contain the closure of $(x, +\infty)$, which is $[x, +\infty)$, which contains $x$.

Comment: So if the closed set $A$ contains the set $B$, it also contains the closure of $B$. How can we prove that? I tried but didn't worked.

Comment: Well, if $B \subset A$, then $\overline{B} \subset \overline{A}$ (why ?). And then, if $A$ is closed, you have...

Comment: I see. We have $A = \overline{A}$ and the result follows. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if $f(x_o)$ was not zero, then there would be a neighbourhood of $x_o$ , say, $N(x_o, \delta)$ in which $f$ is non-zero by continuity of $f$.

But then there exist $x \gt x_o$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ which contradict the hypothesis.!

Comment: How can we prove continuity implies $f$ is non-zero in some neighborhood of $x_0$?

Comment: This is a basic property of continous function that if a continous function $f$ is non-zero at a point then $f$ maintains the same sign in some neighbourhood of that point. You should try to prove that !

Comment: Okay, thank you for your replies.